# Cognitive meaning of כפר

Tags: words, hebrew, kaparah-atonement

What is the cognitive meaning of the root כפר?  It's applications (that I know of, feel free to add) are:

- כפיר - lion cub (Shoftim 14:5)
- כפר - village (Shmuel 1 6:18)
- כופר - Replacement (bamidbar 35:31)
- כפרה - Atonement (Shemos 29:33)
- כפר - Cover (Bereishis 6:14)
- כופר - (Rabbinical word) deny

Is there a common denominator?  (I left out usages that I see as synonymous, such as bribe [similar to replacement]).

Comment: My thoughts - If we assume that the basic definition means "to cover" then some of the definitions are related. Replacement is a "cover up" for the original; atonement "covers up" the sin; a heretic - "covers up" reality (i.e. - the law that people observe.) haven't figured out the idea for "village" or "lion cub", yet.

Comment: Did you check the book (I think its called _An Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language_) based on RSRH's works and the citations to RSRH therein? (I haven't, but doing so may shed light.)

Comment: @DanF Funny enough, my question actually started with village and lion cub, and I tagged the others on as long as I was asking - that's how they ended up first on my list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @DanF pointed out in the comments, the root meaning appears to be 'to cover', in a literal sense ('to smear') or a metaphorical sense ('to replace', 'to atone'). Gesenius and BDB [say as much](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H3722&t=KJV).

Thus you also have *kaporet* (Ex. 25:17) which covers the ark, or *kopher*, the henna plant (Song of Songs 2:14) which is made into a paste and smeared over hands and feet, or *kephor*, the frost which covers the ground (Job 38:47). *Kfar* as village probably originates with a cluster of protected or covered dwellings; *kfir*, they suggest, is a shaggy young lion (i.e. covered with hair or mane).

Cognates of this root with similar meanings are well-attested in Ugaritic, Assyrian, Akkadian, and other languages of the ancient Near East (see, e.g., [Lyonnet](http://books.google.co.ma/books?id=kxl-PDSyQlIC&pg=PA127)).

Comment: I haven't checked it, but I guess [this book](http://amazon.com/dp/1561719420) relates the same root to English _cover_. `:-)`

Comment: Haha @msh210 I bet it does! My dad and I used to read that book for giggles as a kid.

Comment: Hmmm ... I wonder if the dairy product called "kefir" is realted in root origin, somehow. I guess they called it "kefir" b/c it covers the taste of anything you mix into it :-) It's a bit sour.

Comment: @DanF, no, that's not Semitic in origin: see [the etymology of _кефир_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80#Etymology) (from which _kefir_ is derived).